# Need to run several builds for a "release" in TFS. Not sure best approach

Tags: tfs, build, release-management, build-server

We currently use on-prem TFS 2017 (update 1) and have dozens of builds for web projects and services. Some are CI and others attach a publish to the MSBUILD step to actually publish the files to a server (either to stage directly or to a "holding" area for production).

This issue is for a release, we usually need to run 2 or even more builds to encompass a full push of code for a project (such as a web site UI plus one or more service applications). Again, all are done using publish profiles and invoking /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ENVIRONMENTNAME.

I have looked at Releases and not sure if that is the best approach, as it requires artifacts and queue approvers, etc. It also seems to only allow me to choose an EXISTING build instead of kicking off a new one.

All I need is the option to basically kick-off 2 or more existing builds and have them behave as they currently are. Is there a way to aggregate builds into a release AS-IS, or have one build trigger another? What are my options? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can link build pipelines from any of the projects in TFS. You can link multiple build pipelines and specify default values for each of them. You can set up continuous deployment triggers on multiple build sources. When any of the builds completes, it will trigger the creation of a release.

[image]

[image]

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts